# How do I set a title for the exported pdf?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I would like to set some sort of title for the exported data on the PDFs.

I have looked through http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter but there does not seem to be a setting for it.

Right now when  you export data as pdf, you get a grid with some red column headers, but nothing to indicate what the report is supposed to be.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?  I want a title for the exported ui-grid, but have yet to find a solution.  This gives you a title for the exported pdf using pdfmake.      'var docDefinition = {
     info: {
         title: 'LCP'
         
       },
     content: [
               
       {'

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
exporterPdfHeader: { text: "My Header", style: 'headerStyle' },
```

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data